# Ajax toolkit calender extender not working

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-ajax

i added a tab in visual studio toolbox named"AjaxToolkit" and browsed ir with dll file of ajax toolkit(downloaded from microsoft website) i accidently deleted the folder where tool kit was saved now the calender did not appeared on click of the text box , i again downloaded the tool kit and browsed to it tab "AjaxToolkit" but the tab became invisible and when i added a new tab by same name it says "there already exist a tab by the same name"  and if i create a tab by another name and then browse it with tool kit it doesn't show anything inside(like options of calender and all) , the calender doesn't appear , please tell me what to do

Answer (score 0):

Try these tips:

1. Right click on any Toolbox tab and Select 'Show All' menu item
2. Find if your previously added "AjaxToolkit" tab is visible in the list now? (which it should be)
3. If it is empty, remove the tab and recreate and fill it accordingly

OR

You may "Reset Toolbox" altogether, but take cares if any other custom tabs you had added in the past would also get reset by this action. (That may cause projects using controls from those tabs, work improper)